# Returning the sum of comma separated values based on a reference table

Tags: excel, formula, na, calculated-property

I'm creating a spreadsheet where I may have two values in the same cell seperated by commas, such as "Leadership, Activity on Campus". Both of these are worth two different amounts of points. I was trying to create a formula that would allow me to return the sum of both of these and also be able to run the formula again, if a third delimiter was added.

***current table***
[image]

I've tried xlookup, vlookup, i've tried the formulas,

```
=(IF(ISBLANK(B3),0,9)+XLOOKUP(C3,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$35,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$35))) 

=MAKEARRAY(SUM(IFNA(xlookup(trim(TEXTSPLIT(C2,",")),Sheet2!A2:B35,row(Sheet2!A2:35),0)))

=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR("--",XLOOKUP(FILTER("<t><s>" & (SUBSTITUTE(C3,",","</s><s>")  & "</s></t>"), "//s"), Sheet2!$B1, Sheet2!$A1)))
```

And I'm just really stuck. I'm using a drop down list in my excel sheet so there is only certain values that people may add. I coded in the back to allow for multiple values in the drop down menu.

[Sophomores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Hkw.png)

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty0Cz.png)

Sophomores Table
|  Name       | Sport      | Leadership             | Points    |
| :---------- | :--------: | :--------------------: | --------: |
| John Smith  | Basketball | Leadership on Campus   |     18    |
| Jane Doe    | (blank)    | Committee Not          |     14    |
|             |            |  Mentioned, Leadership |           |
|             |            |   on Campus            |           |

Sheet2
|  Points                 | Description              |
| :---------------------- | -----------------------: |
|          9              |  Varsity Sport           |
|          9              | Leadership on Campus     |
|          5              |  Committee Not Mentioned |

The formula is in the Points column. I want each statement in the Leadership column to match the value of Sheet2. For the output of this particular sheet I would expect 18 for John Smith and 14 for Jane Doe. For JOhn Smith I got this number because Basketball is a varsity sport, therefore it is 9 points, plus another 9 points because they are a leader on campus. For Jane Doe I got this value by adding 5 from the committee not mentioned to the 9 from Leadership on campus.

Comment: Your explanation doesn't match with your screenshot. Simply show your input and desired output.

Comment: If you are sharing the formulas please provide the screenshot that shows the column letters and rows, so we can identify in the formula the portion of your screenshot. Thanks

Comment: `=SUM(XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(C3,", "),Sheet2!B2:B35,Sheet2!A2:A35,0))` should work. This can of course be made to spill results for each entry in column C if desired.

Comment: i'm so sorry for not showing a good screenshot hopefully this updated one helps!! @DavidLeal

Comment: @JosWoolley, that formula works but if I change the value in the leadership column, the new number does not update. is there any way to get a dynamic formula that updates dependent on the input?

Comment: @AlyssaCirrincione I think you should paste some **copiable data**, not a picture, and clarify your expected results.

Comment: Is this better? @JosWoolley I tried to create a table

Comment: @AlyssaCirrincione Thanks, but not sure what you mean about the formula I posted not responding to changes in the leadership column. It does precisely that. Share an example for which you feel the result is not what you'd expect.